# Update problem for one to many dependencies in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have some problems to correctly use Entity Framework with one to many relationships.

here is a part of the model :

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    //one to many relationship
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group

    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Group ParentGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Group> ChildGroups { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass

    [Required]
    public int OtherClassID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I have a question about the update an OtherClass entity.

When I get an entity to update, it doesn't have dependencies loaded, I have to add them with an Include like this :

```
using (var db = new DalContext())
{
    var test = db.OtherClasses.Include(o => o.CreatedBy).Single....
}
```

But if I want to update an OtherClass entity, why all dependencies have to be loaded?

To resume, when I want to update an OtherClass entity, CreatedBy dependency must be completely loaded, with the group, and for the group, the parent group and child groups, with users...

Is there a possibility to add or update an entity with only ID attributes filled?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you add your update code?

Comment: using (var db = new DalContext())
{
    var test = db.OtherClasses.Find(1); 
}

Comment: using (var db = new DalContext())
    {
        var test = db.OtherClasses.Find(1); 
        test.name = «Blabla »; 
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

Comment: If I don’t get entity with Include user dependency, SaveChanges throw an exception (created by is required)

Comment: You shouldn't mark `CreatedBy` as required. Add the primitive FK property to the class as a non-nullable property and tell EF it's the FK of `CreatedBy`. Then you can get & update an `OtherClass` entity without loading the user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but here is what I would try:
I believe you should have a UserId in your Group and OtherClass classes, like this:

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    //one to many relationship
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group

    [Required]
    public int GroupID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Group ParentGroup { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Group> ChildGroups { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    
    //If you want to lazy-load the user when you load the Group entity, use virtual
    //Then you don't need the .Include(g=>g.User)
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class OtherClass

    [Required]
    public int OtherClassID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

To update the OtherClass, you update/set the Id properties, not the User property.